# How to sum json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I to sum elements of a JSON array like this, using jQuery:

```
"taxes": [ 
    { "amount": 25, "currencyCode": "USD", "decimalPlaces": 0, "taxCode": "YRI" },
    { "amount": 25, "currencyCode": "USD", "decimalPlaces": 0, "taxCode": "YRI" },
    { "amount": 10, "currencyCode": "USD", "decimalPlaces": 0, "taxCode": "YRI" }
]
```

The result should be:

`totalTaxes = 60`

Comment: 10? Really? 25 + 25 + 10 = 10? And your JOSN is not valid.

Comment: @epascarello: obviously you haven't heard of "new math"

Comment: @Louis:  You forgot the minus sign in front of one of those 25's.

Comment: @epascarello The result is in base-60.

Comment: What is wrong with looping on `taxes[i].amount`?

Comment: @JerminBazazian It doesn't use regular expressions or jQuery.

Comment: I'm sorry totalTaxes should be of course = 60

Comment: @AtesGoral I believe since jQuery is a javascript liberary, you can not have a jQuery only answer. Your solution would be a js solution anyways. Plus as long as JSON is concerned, I don't really think there is any kinda difference between js for loop and jQuery iteration.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Working with JSON 101

```
var foo = {
        taxes: [
            { amount: 25, currencyCode: "USD", decimalPlaces: 0, taxCode: "YRI"},
            { amount: 25, currencyCode: "USD", decimalPlaces: 0, taxCode: "YRI"},
            { amount: 10, currencyCode: "USD", decimalPlaces: 0, taxCode: "YRI"}
        ]
    },
    total = 0,  //set a variable that holds our total
    taxes = foo.taxes,  //reference the element in the "JSON" aka object literal we want
    i;
for (i = 0; i < taxes.length; i++) {  //loop through the array
    total += taxes[i].amount;  //Do the math!
}
console.log(total);  //display the result
```

Comment: Except this isn't JSON.  [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a text format.  This is just javascript object and array notation.

Comment: Thank you. I took a part of a long JSON response. I'm sorry the mistakes in my question. But the sum is working with this.
;)

Answer (score 15):

If you *really must* use jQuery, you can do this:

```
var totalTaxes = 0;

$.each(taxes, function () {
    totalTaxes += this.amount;
});
```

Or you can use the ES5 `reduce` function, in browsers that support it:

```
totalTaxes = taxes.reduce(function (sum, tax) {
    return sum + tax.amount;
}, 0);
```

Or simply use a for loop like in @epascarello's answer...