# Summing in json data with nodejs

Tags: javascript, json

I am using nodejs. I get the json data with the code below.

I want to get the sum of "element.debt". How can I do that ?

so I want to get the sum of "element.debt" in json

```
            var sonuc = 0;
            result.forEach(element => {
                sonuc = element.debt
            });
            console.log(sonuc)
```

```
{
    "message": "customer debst",
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "user_id": 15,
            "debt": "100.00",
            "received_amount": "150.00",
            "business_code": "123456",
            "debt_description": "description here"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "user_id": 15,
            "debt": "110.00",
            "received_amount": "150.00",
            "business_code": "123456",
            "debt_description": "description here"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: sonuc += element.debt inside forEach

Comment: `sonuc += parseFloat(element.debt, 10)` inside forEach

Comment: very thanksssss :))  @kgangadhar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum json array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221455/how-to-sum-json-array)

Comment: Thanks guys, our friend @kgangadhar reply made it easy for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic way to sum the debt using reducer and keeping the decimals

```
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => (parseFloat(accumulator.debt) + parseFloat(currentValue.debt)).toFixed(2);

console.log(result.reduce(reducer));
```